# Open and store a list of JSON files in another list

Tags: python, json, for-loop

I am trying to store a specific JSON file that resides in each subfolder in a root folder.

I managed to do that and now I have this list:

```
list_1
```

which gives:

```
['C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\problem00001\\ground-truth.json',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\problem00002\\ground-truth.json',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\problem00003\\ground-truth.json']
```

Now I am trying to open each of these `JSON` files inside a list but only the last one is stored.
The goal is to store all of them together instead of only the last.

Here is what I tried:

```
for k in list_1:
    with open(k, 'r') as f:
        gt = {}
        gt2=[]
        for i in json.load(f)['ground_truth']:
            #print(i) <--- This here prints exactly what I need
            gt[i['unknown-text']] = i['true-author']
        gt2.append(gt)
```

I guess in each iteration it gets replaced but not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reinitialize gt2 list at every for loop. Therefore it should be outside of the loop.

```
gt2=[]
for k in list_1:
    with open(k, 'r') as f:
        gt = {}
        for i in json.load(f)['ground_truth']:
            #print(i) <--- This here prints exactly what I need
            gt[i['unknown-text']] = i['true-author']
        gt2.append(gt)
```

Comment: Do you think the gt = {} is not necessary?

Comment: I don't know the use-case but it looks like it is not necessary. You can directly use gt2.append(i['true-author']) just after the print(i) line, but i think you want some uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the  local `gt2=[]` varible each and every time after reading the file. You sould define that before iterating the loop over `list_1` as:

```
gt2 =[]
for k in list_1:
    with open(k, 'r') as f:
        gt = {}
        for i in json.load(f)['ground_truth']:
            #print(i) <--- This here prints exactly what I need
            gt[i['unknown-text']] = i['true-author']
        gt2.append(gt)
```